# WCF: Catching Response that is not SOAP

Tags: wcf, soap

I am have been setting up a WCF Client to connect to a Service that I do not have control of (I think the service is implemented in Java).

The service requires Certificate security and I got all the certificates setup but I get the following error when I connect to the endpoint

```
An HTTP Content-Type header is required for SOAP messaging and none was found.
```

I have setup SchemaValidationMessageInspector (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx) to catch the Request and Response.
I can see that the Request is caught but not the response.

As I understand it is because the response is not of the SOAP format meaning that the Validation method is not triggered.

I expect that the real error is a 404, 403, 500 or something like that.
I have been using Wireshark to inspect the packets but it's all encrypted since it's too early in the "stack". I need the response right after the https decryption have occurred.

How can I catch the none SOAP responses so I can see the error in a clear format?

Comment: use Fiddler (easiest), or wcf trace http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madhuponduru/archive/2006/05/18/601458.aspx

Comment: Actually Fiddler showed the problem - It was a 302 Moved. But I was hoping for a code implementation so I don't have to use fiddler in the future

Comment: see my answer just now

Comment: Can't you just use the URL that's in the `Location` header of the `302` response as your endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Use Fiddler or WCF Trace http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madhuponduru/archive/2006/05/18/601458.aspx to see the raw message. If you want to do this from code use a WCF custom messgae encoder http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486.aspx.